# How to map key values of an object based on certain conditions to generate a node map?

Tags: javascript

```
const items = {
  objects: [
    {
      key: 'objec1',
      value: 'main',
    },
    {
      key: 'object2',
      value: 'sub1',
    },
    {
      key: 'object3',
      value: 'sub2',
    },
    {
      key: 'object4',
      value: 'sub3',
    },
    {
      key: 'object5',
      value: 'sec_sub1',
    },
    {
      key: 'object6',
      value: 'sec_sub2',
    },
    {
      key: 'object7',
      value: 'sec_sub3',
    },
    {
      key: 'object8',
      value: 'tert_sub1',
    },
  ],

  links: [
    {
      from: 'objec1',
      to: 'object2',
    },
    {
      from: 'objec1',
      to: 'object3',
    },
    {
      from: 'objec1',
      to: 'object4',
    },
    {
      from: 'object2',
      to: 'object5',
    },
    {
      from: 'object2',
      to: 'object6',
    },
    {
      from: 'object4',
      to: 'object7',
    },
    {
      from: 'object7',
      to: 'object8j',
    },
  ],
}
```

1. So at first we need to scan through items.objects array and then find the key of object with value 'main' (here it will be object1)
2. Next we assign it's position values as the centre of the document., Which will be as follows:

```
    origin = [
      this.el.nativeElement.clientWidth / 2,
      this.el.nativeElement.clientHeight / 2,
    ];
```

3. Then using this centre/origin we will generate circular points around the 'main' object.
   The generation of circular points is as follows:

```
  getCircularPoints(origin, points, radius) {
    const angles = [...Array(points).keys()].map((num) => num * (360 / points));

    const positionMap = angles.reduce(
      (positionMap, angle) => [
        ...positionMap,
        [
          Math.floor(origin[0] + Math.cos(angle) * radius),
          Math.floor(origin[1] + Math.sin(angle) * radius),
          0,
        ],
      ],
      []
    );

    return positionMap;
  }
```

4. Then after assigining positions for objects around the main object we will proceed further to other connections. For other connections originating from the connections around the main object we will generate circular points using the above function.
5. Finally we will generate an objectMap like this:

The idea here is to generate a map of links as follows:

```
const map = {
    objec1: {
        position: [coordx of objec1, coordy of objec1],
        to: {
            object2: {
                position: [coordx of object2, coordy of object2],
            },
            object3: {
                position: [coordx of object3, coordy of object3],
            },
            object4: {
                position: [coordxof object4, coordy of object4],
            },
        },
    },
    object2: {
        position: [coordx of object2, coordy of object2],
        to: {
            object5: {
                position: [coordx of object5, coordy of object5],
            },
            object6: {
                position: [coordx of object6, coordy of object6],
            },
        },
    },
    object4: {
        position: [coordxof object4, coordy of object4],
        to: {
            object7: {
                position: [coordxof object7, coordy of object7]
            },
        },
    },
    object7: {
        position: [coordxof object7, coordy of object7]
        to: {
            object8: {
                position: [coordxof object8, coordy of object8],
            },
        },
    },
}
```

The main idea is to generate a map as follows using the above objectMap:

[image]

I've tried this out in my own way but it is not going beyond objects around the main object (i.e. it is assigning points for objects around main object after that my approach is not working). What I want to achieve is to generate points for all objects in the above manner.

**UPDATE**

SO the idea here is to first fix the main object at the centre of the document. Then using this point generate circular points around this object using the function `getCircularPoints()`. Then using those points again generate the positions of the remaining nodes. Like wise this grows till the tip of each branch.

Comment: Do you have some code of what you have tried so far to achieve what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You could collect all nodes, add the links and build the coordinates.

`to` is an array of nodes names, not the nodes. If wanted just replace with object references. (Actually this solution is without for having the result for `console.log`.)

```js
const
    getCircularPoints = (origin, points, radius) => [...Array(points).keys()]
        .map((num) => num * (360 / points))
        .reduce((positionMap, angle) => [
                ...positionMap,
                [Math.floor(origin[0] + Math.cos(angle) * radius), Math.floor(origin[1] + Math.sin(angle) * radius), 0],
            ],
            []
        ),
    setCoordinates = (reference, node, origin) => {
        reference[node].position = origin;
        getCircularPoints(origin, reference[node].to.length, 50).forEach((c, i) => setCoordinates(reference, reference[node].to[i], c));
    },
    origin = [640 /* this.el.nativeElement.clientWidth / 2 */, 480 /* this.el.nativeElement.clientHeight / 2 */],
    items = { objects: [{ key: 'object1', value: 'main' }, { key: 'object2', value: 'sub1' }, { key: 'object3', value: 'sub2' }, { key: 'object4', value: 'sub3' }, { key: 'object5', value: 'sec_sub1' }, { key: 'object6', value: 'sec_sub2' }, { key: 'object7', value: 'sec_sub3' }, { key: 'object8', value: 'tert_sub1' }], links: [{ from: 'object1', to: 'object2' }, { from: 'object1', to: 'object3' }, { from: 'object1', to: 'object4' }, { from: 'object2', to: 'object5' }, { from: 'object2', to: 'object6' }, { from: 'object4', to: 'object7' }, { from: 'object7', to: 'object8' }] },
    result = {};

items.objects.forEach(({ key }) => result[key] = { position: null, to: [] });
items.links.forEach(({ from, to }) => result[from].to.push(to));

setCoordinates(result, items.objects[0].key, origin);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hi Nina. Will this generates circular points for each node as illustrated above?

Comment: Yeah, But it is not. Can you please help?

Comment: I want to generate a node map as illustrated above. Once we set the origin (that is the object with value 'main') we will generate points around it and then each node will get that point. Then again we will uses those generated points to generate points around those sub nodes. Likewise this grows till there is no more branch for each node. This is the idea

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219734/discussion-between-mex-and-nina-scholz).

Comment: Can you come over the chat?